# Creating c++ maps in a loop in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to create a `cython` function that iterates over two numpy arrays of strings and creates a new list of dicts from the data found therein.

I thought I'd use c++ from cython, iterate through each of these numpy arrays and build up a vector of maps as I go. I can't seem to figure out how to create an empty map on each iteration.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
def extract_data(words_seq, labels_seq, max_sentence_len):
    cdef int i
    cdef vector[map[string, vector[string]]] data
    cdef vector[string] new_entry

    data = []

    for i in range(len(words_seq)):
        cdef map[string, vector[string]] new_row_map = {}
        labels = labels_seq[i]
        words = words_seq[i]

        for j in range(max_sentence_len):
            label = labels_seq[i][j]
            word = words_seq[i][j]

            if label == 'junk':
                continue
            elif new_row_map.count(label) == 0:
                new_entry = [word]
                new_row_map[label] = new_entry
            else:
                new_row_map[label].push_back(word)
        data.push_back(new_row_map)

    return data
```

But I get the error `cdef statement not allowed here`. Also it doesn't like me using a dict literal to declare an empty map.

Answer (score 1):

`cdef` must be used at the function scope level
I mean outside the loop

Comment: How do I do that and create a new map on each iteration? If I declare `new_entry` outside the loop, I just end up appending the same map with new entries in it on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I almost had it right. A copy of the map is appended to the vector on each iteration rather than simply a pointer to the map. So it seems to work if you declare the map outside the loop and then clear it on each iteration.

```
def extract_data(words_seq, labels_seq, max_sentence_len):
    cdef int i, j
    cdef vector[map[string, vector[string]]] data
    cdef vector[string] new_entry
    cdef map[string, vector[string]] new_row_map
    cdef str label, word

    data = []

    for i in range(len(words_seq)):

        for j in range(max_sentence_len):
            label = labels_seq[i][j]
            word = words_seq[i][j]

            if label == 'junk':
                continue
            elif new_row_map.count(label) == 0:
                new_entry = [word]
                new_row_map[label] = new_entry
            else:
                new_row_map[label].push_back(word)
        data.push_back(new_row_map)
        new_row_map.clear()

    return data
```